# Javascript to convert lowercase to upper case

Tags: javascript, html

What is wrong with the following htmla and javascript code

**formToConvert.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ExampleToConvert</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "con.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form id ="myform">
            <input type = "text" id = "field1" value = "Enter text Here"/><br/>
            <input type ="submit" value = "submit" onclick = "convert()"/>
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**con.js**

```
function convert() 
{
    var str ;
    str = document.getElementById("field1");
    document.writeln(str.toUpperCase());
}
```

Why is the above code not giving me the desired result?

Comment: What result does it give you?

Comment: People gets reputation to downvote innocent question, why buddies?

Comment: @SMI: I didn't down vote this question, but the one person who did probably did so because the OP didn't specify the difference between the expected result and the actual result. In other words, they didn't identify the unwanted symptom(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
str = document.getElementById("field1").value;
```

This is because getElementById returns a reference to your HTML Element, not the "text"-value that is contained.

Answer (score 7):

You need to change it to this:

```
var str = document.getElementById("field1").value;
document.writeIn(str.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

The following change should fix your issue:

```
str = document.getElementById("field1");
```

should be

```
str = document.getElementById("field1").value;
```